# DOCTYPE at top of XML breaks Jersey import

Tags: java, jersey

When the xml sent to my jersey web service starts with:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE SyncMessage SYSTEM "example.dtd">
   <SyncMessage version="1.0">
```

It just throws and 400 error immediately and doesn't seem to even recognize it is XML at all.

However when I remove the doctype line so it's as follows:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <SyncMessage version="1.0">
```

Everything works as expected.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious?

Another odd thing is this all worked just fine before I recently upgraded the server to java 8 but I'm thinking that might have more been me lucking into it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is stumbling on this after the fact I did manage to resolve this issue. Let it be noted that jersey 1.8 does not play well with java 1.8, to resolve this I switched to jersey 2.22 and changed around some annotations.